# Spark Default Classes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the `withColumn()` function in my code; however, I haven't imported the class below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

I am wondering why the compiler is not throwing an error. Is this a default class? If so, what are the default classes in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you have to know is the spark version, if you use the Spark the version smaller than 2.0 there is the org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame so you have to use withColumn() from the DataFrame. If you use the Spark version larger than 2.0, you will need to use org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet to use the DataSet withColumn().